# How can I display a HTML file in a WebBrowser in C++

Tags: html, c++, url

I am trying to show an HTML file in a WebBrowser in a Windows program, but it requires a URL. The problem is that I am using a local file. I tried using `file://MyWeb.html` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `file:///MyWeb.html` btw what web control you are using?

Comment: It doesn't work. I think the problem is that I don't know how to introduce the html file into the program source. Or I don't know how to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Give the WebBrowser the full path.
Like

file:///c:/path/to/my.html

refer to link below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows_2

Comment: But I want to build only .exe I don't want to share the html too. Is there any way to introduce it into the code?